# Can the function y=5 be injective or surjective for all x ∈ integers?

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

I have a practice exam and I get kind of confused about:

Is the constant function

***y = 5*** ,     **∀ x ∈** ***Z*** [All integers]

Is this function Injective or Surjective?

Comment: What is the definition of injective? What is the definition of surjective? Can you find an example to show that $y$ is not injective, or an example to show that $y$ is not surjective?

Comment: My guess is that the confusion is not about the definition of injective/surjective, but about how functions are defined.  To clarify this potential misunderstanding, the function being defined is a function that takes any integer as an input and always outputs the number $5$.

Comment: it is not injective, and it may or may not be surjective, depending on your interpretation. It is not surective as a function $Z\to Z$, but it is surjective as a function $Z\to\{5\}$ (most likely the former is intended and you either overlooked it, or it is assumed to be understood from the context).

Comment: I get the point that y always going to be 5.But, why wolfram alpha states y=5 Neither injection, nor surjection?

Comment: because it is neither [injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_function), nor [surjection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surjective_function).

Comment: Is there any indication in the question what the codomain is supposed to be?  For instance, is $f: \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$?

Answer (score 1):

Injective means different elements get mapped to different elements. But, both $1$ and $2$ get mapped to $5$ by this function, so it can't be injective.

Surjectivity depends on the codomain of the function, as noted in the comments.